# java video applet to icecast

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, icecast

I'm putting together a HTML5 based webcast client, but ran into a catch with the webcam streaming.  I currently use icecast to stream the video to the clients, but this has required a different source client for each OS plus an install for each computer.
I have been looking into using a Java Applet until the StreamAPI supports webcam to server, and have seen OpenCV recommended for aquiring the video.  Now I'm trying to find a library to pass the video to Icecast.  Is there such a thing avalible?
I'm also willing to use other applet designs (i.e. flash) if that would be better.

Comment: Not sure if this could help you but [JavaCV does run in applets](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet) and [FFmpegFrameRecorder can write to RTMP servers](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=160#c21)

Comment: Wish this was an answer.  It's exactly what I needed.